# React Hooks useState updating an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm looking to get data from google spreadsheets but I have a problem with React hooks useState.

I have a liste of locations and list of Url . exemple for location 1 : url 1 & location 2 : url 2.

**first render :**

I get by default location 1 and the data fetched from url 1.

`console.log(getTimes)` & `console.log(times)` return data for location 1 from url 1.

**click location 5 :**

I get data from url 1 but I want data from Url 5 !

`console.log(getTimes)` return data from Url 5

`console.log(times)` return data from Url 1

**click location 7 :**

I get data from Url 5 (previews state!).

`console.log(getTimes)` return data from Url 7

`console.log(times)` return data from Url 5

**click location 44 :**

and when I change location 44 I get data now from url 7

`console.log(getTimes)` return data from Url 44

`console.log(times)` return data from Url 7

**==Daily.js==**

```
function Daily({ locationProps = 1, root }) {
      const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
      const localization = useCallback(() => {
        if (root && cookies.get("location") !== undefined) {
          return cookies.get("location");
        }
        return locationProps;
      }, [locationProps, root]);

    const _data = useRef(new Data());

    useEffect(() => {
      _data.current.getTimesFromGoogleSheets();
      }, [locationProps]);


    const getTimes =()=>  _data.current.getTimes();

    const times = useState(()=>getTimes());  <------- here is the problem useState dont update



**==data.js==**
```

```
class Data {
  constructor(locationProps) {
    this.locationProps=locationProps
    this.updateData();
  }

  getTimes(date = null) {
    date = date === null ? moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY') : date;
    var data = this.getData();
    return data ? data[date] : [];
  }

  getSpeadsheetUrl() {
    return config.Data[this.locationProps];
  }



  getTimesFromGoogleSheets() {
    var spreadsheetUrl = this.getSpeadsheetUrl();

    if (!spreadsheetUrl) {
      alert('CSV not set');
    }

    return csvtojson()
      .fromStream(request.get(`${spreadsheetUrl}&_cacheBust=${Math.random()}`))
      .then(json => {
        this.storeData(json);
      });
  }

  storeData(Data = []) {
    var formatted_data = {};
    Data.forEach(day => {
      formatted_data[day.Date] = day;
    });
    window.localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(formatted_data));
    window.localStorage.setItem('Data_lastUpdated', moment().unix());
  }

  getData() {
    var _Data = window.localStorage.getItem('Data');
    return _Data ? JSON.parse(_Data) : null;
  }

  getLastUpdatedTime() {
    return window.localStorage.getItem('Data_lastUpdated');
  }

  updateData() {
    var lastUpdatedDiff = moment().unix() - parseInt(this.getLastUpdatedTime());
    var alreadyHasData = this.getData() ? true : false;
    if (
      lastUpdatedDiff > config.Data.refreshRate * 60 ||
      !alreadyHasData
    ) {
      this.getTimesFromGoogleSheets().then(() => {
        if (!alreadyHasData) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.reload();
          }, 2000);
        }
      });
      console.info('Updating Data....');
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you're using the useState hook wrong, the interface is like this `const [state, updateStateFunction] = useState(initialValue)`. If initialValue is a function, that function is called once before the first render and then never again. So likely you want to instead use the updateStateFunction on each render to change that state.

Comment: Yes but when I write like that I get error   "settimes.map is not a function"

Comment: Because setTimes is not an array, it is a function, perhaps if you share more of your code I can help you further.

Comment: {settimes.map((time,index) =>(
      <span  key={time[index]}>
                  {time[Name]}
                  </span>))}

Comment: ```const [times, settimes] = useState(getTimes());
  useEffect(() => { settimes(getTimes())}, [getTimes()] )```

Comment: But in first code I can Map "times" and now I cant map settimes

Comment: Just so you know why, useState returns an array of two items (or a tuple as they're also called) [times, setTImes]. That's why you could use map before, but the map would not give you the actual times data. First it would give you an array with the times data, and then just the function to setTimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I know so far, you're more likely looking for something like this:

```
function Daily({ locationProps = 1, root }) {
    const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const localization = useCallback(() => {
        if (root && cookies.get("location") !== undefined) {
            return cookies.get("location");
        }
        return locationProps;
    }, [locationProps, root]);

    const _data = useRef(new Data());

    // Use times to display, use setTimes to change the data, maybe as part of your effect?
    const [times, setTimes] = useState(_data.current.getTimes());

    useEffect(() => {
        _data.current.getTimesFromGoogleSheets();
        const newTimes = _data.current.getTimes();
        setTimes(newTimes);
    }, [locationProps]);

    // times.map(...)
}
```

Comment: Happy to help! You can accept the answer if you have no further questions

Comment: TypeError: times.map is not a function :/

Comment: Okay, then I would check what `_data.current.getTimes()` returns, since times will be equal to that. If it doesn't return an array then map won't work but start by checking that!

Comment: -data.curent.getTimes()  RETURN  ```{Date: "03/05/2020", data1: "0", data2: "0"", …}
Date: "03/05/2020"
data1: "0"
data2: "0"
"```

Comment: I add Class ```Data``` from it I get data from google spreadshhet

Comment: So if you do not pass a date parameter you get the full data set which is a Object created from JSON.parse inside your getData function `JSON.parse(_Data)`. You cannot use `.map` on an Object, but you can turn a Object into an array using something like `Object.entries(times).map(...)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: thanks for clarification I try to pass a Date parm to get an array